# What magic items give the owner the ability to possess others like the spell Possession?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, possession

Are there any items that allow the wielder to possess another as if casting the spell [Possession](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/possession/)?

Pathfinder or D&D 3.5 items are accepted.

Comment: You mean like [this *possession* spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/possession/), correct?

Comment: Yessir, or the 3.5 version of the same spell.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked. There is, so far as I'm aware, no *3.5* version of that spell as that spell was originally published in *Occult Adventures* for *Pathfinder.* Is there something *about* the spell that's particularly interesting that makes it perfect for your purposes, or is it just cool?

Comment: My party's warlock wants to do demonic stuff behind the Paladin's back, and he thought this spell was cool. I'm trying to help him figure out how to get it in his kit.

Comment: Why a wand won't fit? He is a warlock, right?

Comment: I'm looking for other items because wands have minimized DC's.

Comment: Yes, but a staff will use your own ability score for its DC. Hence why I didnt even mention wands, they are not worth it for this spell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### On the 3.5 side, any item with the Magic Jar effect will accomplish the task.

---

The most common magic item (and only item that a casual perusal of the DMG, Magic Item Compendium, Complete Mage, Complete Arcane, and a few other books I checked can find) is the **Scroll of Magic Jar**; DMG p.240. The spell is in the PHB, p.250.

It has the advantage of being a published magic item. It has the disadvantage of being usable by wizards and sorcerers and the UMD skill only.

---

However, if that is not to your taste, it is trivially simple to create your own item using the official rules for magic item creation in the DMG. Items created using these rules are technically official, if custom. (DM approval still required.)

A command word item with a customary item body slot (probably head, maybe neck) and once per day usage costs:

- 5          (spell level)
- x9        (caster level)
- x1800  (command word)
- /5         (once per day)

= 16,200 gp.

Double the cost if it doesn't require a body slot (like many wondrous items).

Keep in mind that the *magic jar* spell requires a gem, so your item should either be a gem, or include one.

For flavor, I suggest the
[Crystal Skull of Doom](https://i240.photobucket.com/albums/ff165/brynrees/Crystal_Skull.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

### Very few items for Pathfinder

The [Diadem of Control](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Diadem%20of%20Control) allows you to take possession of constructs.

> The wearer of the headband can assume direct control of the construct as a full-round action, controlling all of the construct’s actions as **possession**. The wearer can end this control at any time as a free action. The wearer can remove the crystal from a construct as a standard action, allowing the wearer to use the crystal on a different construct and returning control of the construct to its original master.

Also, [magic staves](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves/) with the *Possession* spell should also allow that, as long as the spell is also on the character's spell list. However, none of the officially published staves come with the spell. Unlike wands, spells cast from staves uses the owner's ability scores to set the spell's DC, which work much better for offensive spells like this.

Other than that, there are no published items that allow you to affect a creature with *Possession*, not even among artifacts. Your best bet would be to summon a creature that has that ability using a magic item, like an [Ataxian](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ataxian), [Avatarana](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Avatarana), or [Psychemental](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Psychemental).

### The *Possession* spell doesn't exist in D&D 3.5

Being published in the [Occult Adventures](https://paizo.com/products/btpy9egu), [Possession](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/possession/) does not exist in D&D 3.5. Your closest bet being the [Magic Jar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicJar.htm) spell (also 5th level), which is also a relatively stronger effect and different mechanics.

*Possession* was created to allow an earlier effect at "possessing" a creature, which you had to rely on specific monster abilities (such as a [Ghost](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/ghost/)'s) or mimic *Magic Jar* and add restrictions and exceptions at how it works.

For instance, there is no "gem" (receptacle), you can't "hop" between bodies, the target's soul isn't ejected from the body, you are not ejected to a gem if the creature dies, and there is no risk of getting killed by being too far from your body. But other than that, those two spells are very similar.

Considering this, you could look up at any published magic items that use *Magic Jar* and replace it by *Possession* and the item would still behave very similar to how you want. For instance, the [Summon-slave Crystal](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Summon-Slave%20Crystal) allows you to use magic jar on your summoned creatures once per day, and the [Orisian Spirit Jars](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Osirian%20Spirit%20Jars) will allow you to swap your soul between three jars and whoever you targeted with your *Magic Jar* spell.

How, again, none of the published magic items allow you to cast *Magic Jar* either.